# Which part of my Parallel.For should be fixed and is unsafe?

Tags: c#, for-loop, task-parallel-library

I have a nested For loops as follow:

```
    // This loop cannot be parallel because results of the next 
    // two loops will be used for next t
    for (int t= 0; t< 6000000; t++)
        // Calculations in the following two loops includes 75% of all time spend for.
        for (int i= 0; i< 1000; i++)
        {
            for (int j= 0; j< 1000; j++)
            {

                if (Vxcal){V.x= ............. // some calculations    }
                if (Vycal){V.y= ............. // some calculations    }
                // Vbar is a two dimensional array
                Vbar = V;
            }
        }
```

I changed the above code to :

```
    // This loop cannot be parallel because results of the next 
    // two loops will be used for next t
    for (int t= 0; t< 6000000; t++)
        // Calculations in the following two loops includes 75% of all time spend for.
        Parallel.for (0, 1000, i=>
            {
                Parallel.for (0, 1000, j=>
                    {
                        if (Vxcal){V.x= ............. // some calculations    }
                        if (Vycal){V.y= ............. // some calculations    }
                        // Vbar is a two dimensional array
                        Vbar = V;
                    }
            }
```

When I run code results are not correct and takes hours instead of 10 mins. My question is:
Are these kind of For loops suitable for Parallel?
These loops just have some mathematical calculations.
How can I make this parallel For loops safe?

I found a keyword "Lock" which can help me for have a safe loop but which part of this loop is unsafe?

Comment: Where is `V` defined?

Comment: Come to think of it, how does your code even compile? The value `5000000000` is 5 billion. The range of `int` in C# is only 2 billion and change. The statement `t < 5000000000` should give you a compiler error.

Comment: @JimMischel I just put some numbers to show there is a lot of calculations.

Comment: @JacobKrall, V is an array that has x and y dimension. Each dimension was calculated separately and put together as V in VBar. My question is, in this situation what should I do? parallel.For don't give me correct answer.

Comment: @Mehdi would you please update your examples to show how `V` and `Vbar` are defined? I strongly suspect that you are overwriting all your calculations with the statement `Vbar = V;`.

Answer (score 4):

I see you modified your question to put in some other numbers. So your inner loop is now executed 6000000*1000*1000, or 6,000,000,000,000 times. At 4 billion calculations per second (which your computer can't do), that's going to take 1,500 seconds, or 25 minutes. If you get perfect parallelism with `Parallel.For`, you can cut that down to 8.25 minutes on a 4-core machine. If your calculations are long and complicated, there's no surprise that it takes hours to complete.

Your code is slow because it's doing a lot of work. **You need a better algorithm!**

### Original answer

Consider your nested loops:

```
for (int t= 0; t< 5000000000; t++)
    // Calculations in the following two loops includes 75% of all time spend for.
    for (int i= 0; i< 5000000000; i++)
    {
        for (int j= 0; j< 5000000000; j++)
```

The inner loop (your calculation) is being executed 5,000,000,000*5,000,000,000*5,000,000,000 times. 125,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 is a *huge* number. Even if your computer could do that loop 4 billion times per second (it can't--not even close), it would take 31,250,000,000,000,000,000 seconds, or about 990 billion *years* to complete. Using multiple threads on a four-core machine could cut that down to only 250 billion years.

I don't know what you're trying to do, but you'll need a much better algorithm, a computer that's about a 500 billion times faster than the one you have, or several hundred billion processors if you want it to finish in your lifetime.